# On the fly validation for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing my own validation for an input box. It looks for any value filled in the box. If its blank a "tick" won't show, if any characters are found a "tick" will show.

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/sldpH9X4Y2

The tick only appears or disappears when I click away from the input box - how do I make it work whilst typing without having to click away from the box?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var inp = $('input');
        function err() {
            $.each(inp, function () {
                if (!$.trim(this.value)) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('error');
                    // more stuff
                } else {
                    $(this).parent('div').removeClass('error');
                    // more stuff
                }
            });
        }

        inp.blur(err);
    });
```

An example would be great! Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can run the callback on `keyup` event, instead of `change` or `blur`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the moment, your code is called on the `blur` event only (so you have to click away to execute it). If you want to execute it at some others events, just add them. Replace `inp.blur(err);` by this:

```
inp.on('blur keyup keydown paste change input', err);
```

Comment: There's also the 'input' event.

Comment: Nice catch. I forgot this one. Thanks.

Comment: Thankyou very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `inp.blur(err)` to `inp.keyup(err)`.